# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Am I wrong to write directory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I got an error by using Google validation like
[image]

Folder structure is

```
testapp (parent app）
  chosen.jquery.min.js & chosen.min.css & chosen-sprite.png
 -app (child app）
  -templates （folder）
   -menu.js / index.html
```

I wrote in index.html

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
    <select  data-placeholder="Choose" class="chzn-select" style="width:350px;">
    <option value="0">---</option>
    <option value="1" selected>A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="3">D</option>
    </select>

    <select name="type" id="type1">
    <option value="1">a-1</option>
    <option value="2">a-2</option>
    <option value="3">a-3</option>
    <option value="4">a-4</option>
    </select>

    <select name="type" id="type2">
    <option value="5">b-1</option>
    <option value="6">b-2</option>
    <option value="7">b-3</option>
    <option value="8">b-4</option>
    <option value="9">b-5</option>
    </select>

    <select name="type" id="type3">
    <option value="10">c-1</option>
    <option value="11">c-2</option>
    </select>

    <select name="type" id="type4">
    <option value="10">d-1</option>
    <option value="11">d-2</option>
    <option value="11">d-3</option>
    </select>


  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(".chzn-select").chosen();
  $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({allow_single_deselect:true});
  </script>
</html>
```

What is wrong in my code?Am I wrong to write directory?By using Network of Google validation,[image]

I found chosen.jquery.min.js was not load.How can I fix this?

Comment: This is simply a path error. Is the chosen js file in the same folder as the HTML? If not, you'll need to amend the path

Comment: did you try to use {% load static %} ???  and then give src like this src="{% static "yourfile" %}"

Comment: @MananKalariya I cannot understand ur messages.If I use {{ loadstaticfiles }},how should I write it?Could u write codes in answer or comments?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thx ur comments.I moved chosen.jquery.min & chosen.min.css & chosen-sprite.png into same folder with HTML.However,only chosen.jquery.min cannot load and 404 error happens.How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you need to understand about Django static files [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/)

setup your setting.py as given in ***documentation***

After that in your HTML or base.html(if you are extending the other HTML)

add at the top

```
{% load static %}
```

and then your file

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}"></script>
```

i think this should work

(first, you need to give path for this like given in documentation)

also, try  this command for all your staticfiles will come in the static folder.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

After this command, all your static files will be in this and you can easily add and remove from static folder only